# How to create lettered lists using Quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

In `R-Markdown` you can *automatically* create lettered lists using the following code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2022-07-21"
output: html_document
---

# Example

a) something
a) something
```

Output:

[image]

I tried using the same commands in `Quarto`:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html 
editor: visual
---

a) something

a) something
```

Output:

[image]

So I was wondering if it is possible to automatically create lettered lists in `Quarto`?

Comment: Though for some reason, I can't see the images (most probably, due to a network issue from my end), Your code actually working for me, that is, I am getting numbered list

Comment: Hi @shafee, thank you for your response. I know that it generates a lettered list, but now you should manually change the letters every time like a,b,c for example, while in rmarkdown you can do a,a,a which returns in a,b,c as you could see on the image (if your network is fixed maybe). Another thing is that in Quarto the list is not aligned that well, while in rmarkdown you can see that is nicely aligned.

Comment: No, even if I use a, a, a, quarto rendering it as a, b, c in the output for my case, also I am not seeing any problem with alignment. Should I post an answer with the image of my output? @Quinten

Comment: @shafee, That would be great if possible, thanks for your input!

Comment: I have added the pic of the rendered output, hopefully I got it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html 
---

this is a numbered list

1) something 1 
1) something 2

this is lettered list

a) something
a) something
a) something
a) something
```

[image: list in quarto]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you run this in a separate chunk? When I run this in a chunk, I don't get your results like that.

Comment: I ran this exactly as it is posted here. Sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean by separate chunk here ??

Comment: it works thanks! I meant that it didn't work if I run your code outside the chunk.